# Twitter Bootstrap is not changing color table header row's color while using <th> instead of <td>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my rails 3.2 application I have to display a table. So I used the twitter bootstrap's class **"table table-bordered"** to format it. And then to change it's rows color I also used class "info" and "success" described [here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#tables).

The table code in my page is as follows:-

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr class="info">
    <th>Your Links</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <tr class="success">
    <td><%= link_to linkbunch_url(link.link), linkbunch_url(link.link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', linkbunch_url(link.link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_url(link.link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', destroy_url(link.link), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure ?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Guess what it's changing all rows colors except the first row that is the the head row of table. But when changed the **""** to **""** then it's working fine. But because it's just a simple row not a table header row so it's fonts are not bold type.

So How to change the header row's color without using the  instead of  ??

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no css in bootstrap for adding `.info` or `.success` to the table header. You have to make the rule yourself.

```
.table tbody tr.info th {
    background-color: #d9edf7;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/fsW8K/4/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th>Your Links</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<% @links.each do |link| %>
  <tr class="success">
    <td><%= link_to linkbunch_url(link.link), linkbunch_url(link.link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', linkbunch_url(link.link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_url(link.link) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', destroy_url(link.link), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure ?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```